# Can we extend hypercomplex numbers more?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, hypercomplex-numbers

In the hypercomplex numbers we describe units as $e_n$ for example,
$e_0 = 1, e_1 = i, e_2 = j, e_3 = k ...$
if x is an hypercomplex we can present as
$x = x_0e_0+x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3+x_4e_4+...$

Can we extend this units to negative of n for example what is $e_{-1}$?
Can we reach thats units properties using general formulas at hypercomplex numbers?

Comment: The use of terminology "Hypercomplex numbers" is ... complex. The good framework for them is "Clifford algebras".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such notion of just "hypercomplex numbers". For instance, for $n=4$ you can combine several different hypercomplex units to get different algebras.

For instance, if you take $i^2=-1$, $j^2=1$, $k^2=-1=(-ij)^2$, you get tessarines.
If you take $j_1^2=1$, $j_2^2=1$, $j_3^2=1$, you get 4-dimensional split-complex (hyperbolic) numbers.
If you take $i^2=-1$, $\varepsilon^2=0$, you get dual complex numbers.
If you take $j^2=1$, $\varepsilon^2=0$, you get dual split-complex numbers.
If you take $\varepsilon^2=0$, $\epsilon^2=\varepsilon$, you get another algebra that I do not know if has a name.

All the above systems are commutative and associative.

If you include non-commutative systems, then you also can get quaternions ($i^2=-1$, $j^2=-1$, $k^2=-1$), split-quaternions, Grassmann numbers, etc.

As you can see, in 4 dimensions we can build at least 8 different hypercomplex systems up to isomorphism.

Thus, you can combine hypercomplex units with various properties in any order to get different systems. Since in positive dimentions you can construct different algebras, it is unclear, how to talk about negative dimensions.